# Regex whole dollar amount with optional dollar sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using jQuery to test input of a dollar amount that accepts whole dollar amounts (no decimals) and with the dollar sign as optional and at the start.

I have `/^[$0-9]+/` but doesn't work.

```
Valid Numbers:

$100
100

Invalid:

$100.00
100.00
0.99
```

Edit: I am using jQuery test method

Comment: How are you testing it? You need to include anchors if you're just using that with `Regexp.test`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/^\$?\d+$/
```

Breakdown:

```
^    start of string
\$   literal dollar
  ?  optional
\d   digit
  +  one or more
$    end of string
```

Comment: awesome. Thanks for the breakdown, helps a lot.

Comment: You need an extra \ on the dollar sign if using jquery. Argh.